# capturing values in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

I do not understand how **capturing values** works. Below an example of a nested function that captures *amount* and *runningTotal* from its surrounding function. when calling makeIncrementer(forIncrement:) function, nothing happens inside incrementer() function (the code inside incrementer() function doesn’t get executed), so how can incrementer() capture any value? I’m obviously a novice in programming and I couldn’t find a detailed explanation of what is actually going on “under the hood”.

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0
    func incrementer() -> Int {
        runningTotal += amount
        return runningTotal
    }
    return incremented
}

let incrementByTen = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)
incrementByTen()
// returns a value of 10
incrementByTen()
// returns a value of 20
incrementByTen()
// returns a value of 30
```

Comment: Have you read this documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: yes, I have read the documentation. the piece of code above was excerpted from  Apple’s documentation

Comment: Any clarifications? It's unclear to me

Answer (score 0):

That's how closures work -- they capture variables from the surrounding scope when they are *created*.